# What do you call this object in Java and why do you use?

Tags: java

So I'm working on with two class now and just learned to do this, yet still don't know why is this possible and what this is called. Class variable? Objects creating objects? 
And in the setter method, why the default value is null? is it like String?
From what I'm assuming, 'RetailItem item' is like it combined the whole RetailItem class and creating a new variable in another class with its feature.

There are two classes named CashRegister and RetailItem.

Here goes the instance 'RetailItem item' from CashRegister with a setter.

---

```
public class CashRegister
{
    private RetailItem item;

    public void setItem (RetailItem newItem)
    {
        if (newItem != null)
        {
            item = newItem;
        }else{
            item = new RetailItem();
        }
    }
}
```

---

`RetailItem()` is a default constructor from `RetailItem` class.
What does `item = new RetailItem();` mean?
I don't know where am I even going to start studying. What am I missing?

Comment: It means, if `item` is `null`; that the code defaults to creating (and assigning) a new instance of `RetailItem` with empty constructor arguments.

Comment: This is all extremely basic code. It's not at all clear what you're confused by. Please be more specific.

Comment: The call to `new` invokes the default constructor you mentioned, and returns a new instance, that is, gives birth to a new object in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some trouble understanding your English, so I might have misinterpreted  some of your questions.

> What do you call this object in Java and why do you use?

I don't know which "object" you are referring to.

> ... yet still don't know why is `this` possible and what `this` is called.

It is just called `this`.  There is no other term for it.

> Class variable?

No.  `this` is not a class variable.

> Objects creating objects?

(Huh?)  No.  `this` is not "objects creating objects".

> And in the setter method, why the default value is null?

Because that is the way that Java defined.  Any instance variable (like `item`) whose type is a *reference type* has a default initial value of `null`.

(Why?  Because that is the only value that makes sense from a language perspective.  Anything else, and there would need to be some way for the programmer to say what the default is.  Compilers can't read your mind!)

> is it like String?

Not sure what you mean.  But if you are asking if you would get the same default value behavior if `item` had been declared with type `String`, then Yes.

> From what I'm assuming, `RetailItem item` is like it combined the whole `RetailItem` class and creating a new variable in another class with its feature.

Not exactly.  What `RetailItem item` is actually doing is *declaring a variable* in which you may then put a reference to a `RealItem` object.  This variable has the default value `null` .... until some other value is assigned to it.

> What does `item = new RetailItem();` mean?

That means create (construct) a new `RetailItem` instance (an object), and then assign its reference to the variable `item`.

> I don't know where am I even going to start studying.

I recommend that you start with a good introductory Java textbook, or the Oracle Java Tutorial, or your course lecture notes.  Ask your teachers.

But keep at it.  If you work at it, you will get to the point where it all starts to make sense.  Because, basic Java is a simple and consistent language.  The language only gets complicated when you learn about generics, type inference / lambdas and .... multi-threading.

Comment: I didn't mean to highlight 'this' as if it's a variable. Maybe I'm still not used to use this website but thank you for your detailed answer and suggestions even though my question was crappy.

Comment: *"I didn't mean to highlight 'this' as if it's a variable."* - I was trying to make some sense out of the first 30 or so words of your question.  That was the only interpretation that made sense to me.